# Facebook og: tags not found - operation timeout (Meteor)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, meteor, meta-tags

I'm working on a meteor application and trying to get the Facebook meta data to show up when people share links.  We are using Iron Router and would eventually like to have dynamic meta content, but for now I'm just trying to get static meta content to work.  I read a lot of suggestions about spiderable, but I think that's more so for serving up dynamic content.  Maybe I'm mistaken?

I have been using Facebook debugger, but I'm not really sure what to do with the errors it provides.  I get the following errors when entering our website URL in the Facebook debugger:

1) Object at URL 'https://www.mywebsiteURL.com' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

2) Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

3) **Errors That Must Be Fixed** Object Missing a Required Value - Object at URL 'https://www.mywebsiteURL.com' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

We definitely do have an og:title, so I don't think that's actually the problem.

It seems like because of the timeout it's not fetching anything. I have one header block and when I do a 'fetch as google' from the google webmaster tools it doesn't have a problem fetching the webpage header.  The download time was 0.084 seconds.  I recently did a new indexing request, but I don't think this would cause an issue with Facebook's scraper.

From my index.html file:

```
<head>
  <title>Company Name</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Description here">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>   
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="image path">

  <!-- Facebook Meta -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="My Page Title"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="My Website title"/>
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.mywebsiteURL.com" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="MyImagePath" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Website Description" />

  <!-- Twitter Meta -->
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="@companyname" />
  <meta name="twitter:title" content="My page title" />
  <meta name="twitter:description" content="My page description" />
  <meta name="twitter:image" content="My image path" />
  <meta name="twitter:url" content="https://www.mywebsiteURL.com" />
</head>
```

I'm pretty stumped.  Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: I'm using this package https://atmospherejs.com/manuelschoebel/ms-seo and I got very good results, I can event share dynamic data in fb with dynamic images too. :)

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot and let you know if it works out.

Comment: Unfortunately I still haven't been successful.  I used the package and it seems like it's providing the header data to the DOM, but FB scraper still has the same errors.  There seems to be a websocket error occurring when I check the console.  I wonder if that might have something to do with the timeout error from FB.  The error is: WebSocket connection to "..." failed: ...  Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Comment: fb caches the url data for some time If you want updated data go to this url https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and enter your url and click on `debug` then click on fetch new scrap this will fetch new data, This will not work in local I think

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, but I've been fetching new scrapes each time.  Same errors.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up resolving this by downloading the [Spiderable package](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-the-spiderable-package#!).  I'm not entirely sure why Facebook's scraper wasn't able to get static meta content in the HTML header when it appeared the Google bot could.

I used Homebrew to install PhantomJS.  Don't forget to include `this.ready()` in your publish functions if you're not returning a cursor!